# How to know if specified object in ArrayList is null?

Tags: java, null, arraylist

I want to know if an Object in an ArrayList is null. If it's null, then it shouldn't do anything. Example:

```
if(!(theList.get(theIndexofObject) == null)){
   do something...
}
else{
   do nothing...
}
```

This doesn't work, because it throws an exception cause of the '.get()'-method. Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: What exception? If it's a NullPointerException, *the list* is null, not the object. Also, `ArrayList#get()` asks for an int (the object index), not an object.

Comment: are you sure your ArrayList itself isn't null? and you've got your program logic backwards according to what you stated.

Comment: ArrayList has a get method that takes an object?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. the only get method ArrayList exposes accepts an integer argument.

Comment: my ArrayList isn't null I know that. and the get-method returns an element at the specified index - sorry if it's confusing cause i wrote object...

Comment: the argument i use is an index, but i want to know, if the element with this index is null.

Comment: You still haven't told us what exception you're getting...

Comment: sorry for that but it isn't relevant what exception i get.
I know the problem is the get-method:
i want tho know if in the list at the position of the index is no element. i only know the get-method but it crashes if i want to get an element where is no element...hope you understand the problem know

Comment: @Dominik the piece of code you provided shouldn't throw an exception, because it is perfectly valid to check if list.get(index) == null (see: [http://ideone.com/BGGQM](http://ideone.com/BGGQM)), so I think the problem is somewhere else and you should really paste here the Exception you were getting....

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) Method of your list:

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably confused about how to use the API. Here is a simple example of how it works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NullItems {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Object> items = new ArrayList<Object>();
        items.add("foo");
        items.add(null);
        items.add(25);

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            Object item = items.get(i);
            if (item != null) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }

        // or shorter:
        for (Object item : items) {
            if (item != null) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `get` method wrong. You need to pass the index an item is at to the `get` method. You could use the `contains` method to see if the object is in the ArrayList.

Example:

```
if(theList.contains(theObject))
   //do something
```

Otherwise you could use a try and catch which seems confusing and hard to read so I would strongly not recommend doing the following but have included it to show you:

```
for(int i=0; i<theList.size(); i++)
{
    try
    {
       if(!(theList.get(i) == null))
       {
           //do something
       }
       else
       {
           //do nothing
       }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe)
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Alternatively use a for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

In javaScript itemArray.length,  for java u have to use ARRAY.size() insted of length function

```
 var itemArray=//Assign some list of value;
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++){

          if(itemArray[i].value == null){
             Do nothing
              }else{
                 Do something
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that your arraylist is null chang first condition to:

```
if(theList!=null && !(theList.get(theIndexofObject) == null)){
    // do something...
}
else{
    // do nothing...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method arrayList.size() returns the number of items in the list - so if the index is greater than or equal to the size(), it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(!(theList.get(theIndexofObject) == null)){
   do something...
}
else{
   do nothing...
}
```

instead of writing this code.Try in the below format,I think you will get answer

```
if(theList.get(theIndexofObject)!= null)){
   do something...
}
else{
   do nothing...
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem OP is encountering.

Comment: You did same thing in reverse order.